"Essere contrario a": un'eccezione nell'uso della particella "ci"
Qualcuno mi potrebbe spiegare perché "Sono contraria a questo" non può riformularsi in "Ci sono contraria"? Secondo la grammatica la particella ci può sostituire "a ciò", come nei casi "Ci sono abituata", "Non farci caso", "Ci ho pensato", ma nel caso "sono contraria a ..." non funziona.
Un'altra domanda: perché è preferibile dire "Voglio parteciparvi" e non "Ci voglio partecipare"?
Grazie.

Penso sarebbe meglio separare le due domande in due post diversi.

Sono due domande correlate, entrambe riguardanti uso della particella CI.

Si potrebbe ignorare la domanda 2, perché è la prima che mi sgomenta.

Fa bene a sgomentarti, perché “Ci sono contraria” suona come una storpiatura scherzosa (o forse qualche forma regionale che io ignoro). Sicuramente non è italiano standard. Dove l'hai letto o sentito?

@DaG  Non l'ho sentito da nessuna parte, invece ho visto "ne sono contrario" che mi ha fatto venire dubbi. Secondo le mie conoscenze grammaticali, se qui ci voleva una particella, bisognava usare "ci". Poi ho scoperto che nemmeno "ci" era ammesso, tantomeno "ne". Quindi è rimasto un mistero. Il fatto che "ci" non è ammesso mi sgomenta.

Ah, grazie, ora capisco meglio la tua domanda: pensavo che avessi trovato da qualche parte una frase costruita in quel modo.

Immagino che sia qualcosa di simile a quanto spiegato nelle risposte a questa domanda. Cioè, si tratterebbe semplicemente di un costrutto non idiomatico, non di un problema grammaticale.

@Charo Molti italiani mi hanno confermato che "ci sono contraria" è proprio sbagliato, cioè bisogna evitarlo assolutamente.

Siccome nessuno qui ha dato una risposta, incollo la risposta di Alberto Arceri che è un linguista, spero che possa essere utile a chi visualizza questa domanda:

“Essere contrari a” sembra far parte di un gruppo di costruzioni che dovrebbero cliticizzare l'argomento preposizionale introdotto da “a” tramite i locativi “ci” o “vi”, se codifica un referente inanimato, e tramite i clitici dativali in caso di referente umano.
“Il destino gli è contrario” (“gli” 'a lui' argomento dativale umano).
“Il vento ci è contrario” (“ci” 'a noi' argomento dativale umano).
“Tale contratto non dovrebbe ritenersi vietato, perché nessun interesse inderogabile vi è contrario” (“vi” 'al contratto' argomento allativale inanimato; https://shorturl.at/15oWA).
Tuttavia se il clitico locativo “vi” è senz'altro ritenuto di registro elevato dai parlanti, il locativo “ci” è evitato (forse perché accostato al “ci” dativale substandard: “Adesso ci dico la verità”, con “ci” per 'gli/le/loro'). Il vuoto creato da questo rigetto recentemente sembra essere in parte colmato dall'impiego del clitico “ne” (che secondo la norma estrae argomenti introdotti da “di” e “da”, non da “a”).
“Cosa è il MES e perché il M5S ne è contrario?” (“ne” 'al Mes' inanimato; https://shorturl.at/kZCiv).
L'impiego innovativo di “ne” per “ci/vi” ha attirato l'attenzione degli studiosi (Lombardi Vallauri 2018 https://shorturl.at/bGCR7 Miola 2023 https://shorturl.at/BnuqQ).
Le costruzioni che hanno argomenti tra il dativale e il locativo(/strumentale), anche quando non si insinua il “ne” (“ne è contrario”, “ne è allergico”, “ne fa ricorso”, “ne accenna” ecc.), sono un'area delicata della grammatica (“ci/ti/gli parlo”, “ci/?*ti/?*gli rinuncio”, “lo/*gli penso” ecc.).
“Ne fa cenno” o “vi fa cenno”? Qui entrambe le opzioni sembrano standard.)
L'estensione di “ne” compare in vari tipi di predicati (verbi semplici: “ne ha alluso”; costruzioni con verbo supporto o predicati complessi: “ne dà rilievo”, “ne è entrato in contatto”; costruzioni copulative: “ne è allergico”). Il massimo esperto del tema è Emanuele Miola.


Miola 2023 immagino sia questo: https://www.researchgate.net/journal/Sociolinguistica-International-Yearbook-of-European-Sociolinguistics-Internationales-Jahrbuch-fuer-europaeische-Soziolinguistik-1865-939X/publication/370099534_The_new_ne_an_incipient_restandardization_process_in_contemporary_Italian/links/64b54e148de7ed28baa47fa6/The-new-ne-an-incipient-restandardization-process-in-contemporary-Italian.pdf?_tp=eyJjb250ZXh0Ijp7ImZpcnN0UGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uIiwicGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uRG93bmxvYWQiLCJwcmV2aW91c1BhZ2UiOiJwdWJsaWNhdGlvbiJ9fQ.

Qual è la fonte di questo testo? Un libro, un articolo, una comunicazione personale? Se citi un testo di qualcuno ne dovresti dare gli estremi completi.

@DaG È la sua risposta alla mia domanda posta su Facebook.

Aggiungo un uso non convenzionale di ne: Ne vado matta. Qui ne sostituisce per qualcosa. L'italiano è molto capriccioso, le eccezioni sono infinite e le regole date spesso non sono esaurienti.
